# Law of convolution of two distributions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-explanation, convolution, characteristic-functions

I'm currently trying to understand the proof that probability distributions are uniquely defined by their characteristic functions.

One of the relevant lemmas starts like this

\begin{aligned}
&\text { Proposition } 10.12 \text { Let } P \text { be a probability distribution on } \mathbb{R}^{d} \text { . Let } P^{\sigma}=P*\mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma^{2} I\right)=\\
&\mathcal{L}(X+\sigma Z) \text { where } X, Z \text { are independent with } \mathcal{L}(X)=P \text { and } \mathcal{L}(Z)=\mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma^{2} I\right), \sigma>0
\end{aligned}

For two independent random variables the convolution is given by

> $$
> P(X+Z\in B) = P_X*P_Z(B)$$

I don't understand why, given that $\mathcal{L}(Z)=\mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma^{2} I\right)$ and $\mathcal{L}(X)=P$, the law for $P^\sigma$ is given by $\mathcal{L}(X+\sigma Z)$ and not $\mathcal{L}(X+Z)$.

Comment: You are right. Perhaps $\mathcal L (Z)$ was suppposed to be $\mathcal N(0,1)$.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit further as to why $\mathcal{L}(Z)$ is supposed to be $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$