# Proof that a probability distribution is uniquely determined by its characteristic function.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, proof-explanation, convolution, characteristic-functions

I'm currently working through the proof in my lecture notes for the statement that a probability distribution is uniquely determined by its characteristic function. However, I got stuck on quite a few points.

One lemma necesarry for this proof used states the following:

> Proposition $10.12$ Let $P$ be a probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}^{d} .$ Let $P^{\sigma}=P * \mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma^{2} I\right)=$ $\mathcal{L}(X+\sigma Z)$ where $X, Z$ are independent with $\mathcal{L}(X)=P$ and $\mathcal{L}(Z)=\mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma^{2} I\right), \sigma>0$
> Then $\hat{P}^{\sigma}(t)=\hat{P}(t) e^{-\frac{\|t\|^{2} \sigma^{2}}{2}}$ and $P^{\sigma}$ has the density
> $$
> f^{\sigma}(x)=\frac{1}{(2 \pi)^{d}} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} \hat{P}(-t) e^{-\frac{\|t\|^{2} \sigma^{2}}{2}} e^{i<x, t>} d t .
> $$

However there actually seems to be some [notation error](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4186846/law-of-convolution-of-two-distributions) in the lectures notes because later on in the proof $\mathcal{L}(Z)$ is said to be $\mathcal{N}\left(0,I\right)$.

> Theorem $10.13$ Let $P$ be a probability distribution on $\mathbb{R}^{d} .$ Then it is uniquely determined by $\hat{P}$. Moreover
>
> 1. for each bounded and $P$ -a.s. continuous function $h$ we get
>    $$
>    \int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}} h(x) d P(x)=\lim _{\sigma \rightarrow 0} \int f^{\sigma}(x) h(x) d x
>    $$

Proof.

1. Clearly $\int f^{\sigma}(x) h(x) d x=E(h(X+\sigma Z))$ where $X$ and $Z$ are independent with $\mathcal{L}(X)=$ $P$ and $\mathcal{L}(Z)=\mathcal{N}(0, I) .$ By dominated convergence this converges to $E(h(X))=$ $\int h(x) d P(x)$ as $\sigma \rightarrow 0$. Uniqueness follows, since $\hat{P}$ determines all $f^{\sigma}$ and hence all integrals $\int h d P$.

Now my questions regarding the proof are the following:

1. Why is $f^{\sigma}(x) h(x) d x=E(h(X+\sigma Z))$ and not $E(h(X+Z))$?
2. Why is $E(h(x))=\int h(x) d P(x)$?
   Specifically, why are we integrating over $P$ all of a sudded instead of $x$?

If my interpretation is correct, this part of the proof (there is a second statement regarding distributions with densities) shows that characteristic functions uniquely determine their corresponding probability distributions because we can set $h(x) = 1_{(-\infty,x]}$ and get the cumulative distribution function back.

Comment: I currently am too busy to study the intricacies needed to answer 1. But about 2.: This is basically the definition of an expected value. If you have a real random variable $Y$ over a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\mathsf P)$, then, by definition, $$\mathsf E(Y)=\int_{\Omega} Y\,\mathrm d\mathsf P.$$ If $\mathsf P_Y$ denotes the pushforward measure of $\mathsf P$ under $Y$, then, by the "Transformationssatz" (change of variables in english), we have $$\int_{\Omega}Y\,\mathrm d\mathsf P=\int_{\mathbb R} y\,\mathrm d\mathsf P_Y(y).$$ For you, $Y=h(X)$.

Comment: Well, I still appreciate your help! Danke!